# ¿cómo llamar los formularios de una plantilla desde la vista en django?

Tags: django

Soy un principiante.
Podría mandar llamar desde mi vista los formularios que tengo una plantilla html? Esta plantilla contiene botones, checkbox, inputtext, los cuales puse directamente en el html, lo que desea saber es si hay alguna forma manipularlos desde la vista para construir la lógica de cada uno de los elementos?
Proyecto de escuela.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, no pongas imagenes de tu codigo, pon directamente tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Te explicaré de forma simple como funciona django para trabajar con formularios en templates.

### Modelo

Lo primero es crear un modelo en tu archivo models.py. Ejemplo:

```
class Modelo(models.Model):
     campo1 = models.IntegrerField()
     campo2 = models.IntegrerField()
```

### Formulario

Una vez tienes el modelo crea un formulario a partir de tu modelo. Ejemplo:

```
class Formulario(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Modelo
       fields = '__all__'
```

### Vista

Una vez tenemos el formulario debemos enlazar una vista (view) con ese formulario para poder pasarselo a un template. Hay 2 formas de realizar vistas, con clases o funciones. Esta segunda se usa para realizar vistas personalizadas. Te pondre un ejemplo de clases:

```
class Vista(views.CreateView):
    model = Modelo
    form = Formulario
```

### Template

De esta forma ahora tendrás una variable dentro de template, que especifiques en la vista, llamado `{{form}}`, el cual será tu formulario. Llamando a dicha variable obtendras el formulario al completo, tienes la opción de llamar a cada campo de esta forma `{{form.campo1}}` para obtener 1 campo específico en caso de necesitarlo a la hora de maquetar tu template.

Por otra parte dentro de tu formulario puedes decir dentro de la variable fields los campos que quieres mostrar y los que no, relacionados con tu template.